# Identificar servidor de banco de dados (homologação e produção) em dois ambientes diferentes

Tags: banco-de-dados, amazon-aws, host

Como na maioria dos casos, tenho dois ambientes: homologação e produção, tanto para o servidor como para o banco de dados.

Gostaria de saber como faço para utilizar um mesmo endereço (host) do banco de dados nas configurações da aplicação (em PHP) onde, quando estiver sendo rodado em ambiente de homologação, o host apontasse para o banco de homologação, quando em produção, o host apontasse para o banco de produção, evitando assim, ajustar o host do banco de dados sempre que o servidor fosse promovido para produção (deploy).

Comment: O host é até simples, você poderia apontar no seu /etc/hosts para endereços diferentes ou usar um DNS "interno" que resolva para nomes diferentes. Mas além dos hosts, tem as credenciais de autenticação e outras variáveis de ambiente, mais recomendável que o host seja configurável, assim como o resto.

Comment: Se seu objetivo é não ter que mudar o código entre homologação e produção, minha sugestão é seguir as diretrizes de [configuração em 12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/pt_br/config). Faça sua aplicação ler o nome do host (e port, nome do banco, login, senha) de uma variável de ambiente. Em cada ambiente você configura as variáveis como quiser e o seu código não precisa ser tocado: o mesmo que rodou em homologação rodará em produção.